# Why AngularJS prints double quotation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

With AngularJs, I am trying to display currency exchange with image. Here is my Razor code below.

```
<span ng-controller="CurrencyController">
     <span ng-bind="currencies"></span>
</span>
```

and I am sending the below text from controller

```
string text = "Dollar : 1.7 <img src=\"~/Images/Currency/up.png\">";
```

when the HTML is rendered, I took a look at the source in Chrome, and I saw the HTML below...

```
<span class="ng-binding">
     "Dollar: 1.7 <img src="~/Images/Currency/down.png">"
</span>
```

Why is the rendered text in HTML is surrounded with double quotation? how can I fix this?

Comment: try to use single quotes in the string instead of use double quotes and escape the ones inside.

Comment: Isn't `ngBindHtml` should be used?

Comment: @Satpal, where should I use ngbindHtml?

Comment: `<span ng-bind-html="currencies"></span>` as you are rendering `img` element

Comment: <span ng-bind-html="currencies"></span> or <span ng-bind=currencies></span>

Comment: @Satpal, it didnt work

Comment: I think this link help you @ArifYILMAZ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using ng-bind-html, as stated in the docs, is the directive used to render html.
ng-bind should only be used if you cant to render a simple html text node.

So, your code should look like this:

```
<span ng-controller="CurrencyController">
   <span ng-bind-html="currencies"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: it didnt work. and I still dont know how to fix this